# Unescaped HTML unicode in Migration notice on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, unicode, migration-notice

While I was reading [this meta post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271712/who-watches-the-watchmen) with official Android app, I noticed that it has been migrated to **Stack Overflow em Português**'s meta... or was it **`Portugu&#234;s`**? (removing the code block will render the unicode correctly on question body).

I couldn't check how it was shown in web browser because it automatically redirected me to the migration target, but I assumed it was rendered correctly just as how browser normally renders HTML unicodes.

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.48
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 4.4.4

[image: Português instead of Português]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice catch! This is fixed for the next update (anything with a version greater than 1.0.49):

[image]