# Badge indicator is too large relative to other text on Android App

Tags: support, badges, android-app

*Not to be confused with [Moderator diamond is too large relative to other text on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176715/moderator-diamond-is-too-large-relative-to-other-text-on-android)*.

Well, I just updated my Nexus 4 to Android 5.0 Lollipop. Nothing is wrong, all work well, no problem with app compatibility, and it's a good time to browse Stack Exchange... uh, were those badge indicators *that* large?

> [image: those are laaaarge!]

- Stack Exchange: 1.0.51
- Android model: Nexus 4
- Android version: 5.0

For comparison, this is from SE 1.0.51 on Galaxy S3, Android 4.0.4 taken from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243052/questions-and-answers-are-all-skewed-cant-read)

> [image: normal!]

And this is from SE 1.0.48 on Nexus 4, Android 4.4.4 taken from [my previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239678/unescaped-html-unicode-in-migration-notice-on-android-app)

> [image: normal too!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue specific to Android 5.x Lollipop, and possibly related to Android system font.

On Android 6.0 Marshmallow, the badge size is back to normal (but then [there's another "problem"...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267504/why-is-the-mod-diamond-red-in-android))

[image: normal badge size]